# Not include :before content on a link be focused

Tags: css

I have the css code which is similar with following code. (I cope it from http://jsfiddle.net/LmvgM/8/ thanks @thirtydot). When the link is focused, I found the :before content was included.

So how can I remove it from highlight box, let the box only has the text, no '>'.

[image]

```
box.blueb a { 
    color: #0098aa; 
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.box.blueb a:before { 
    content: "> "; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.box.blueb a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You're not clear about what you want. If I understand. you just want to delete the position: absolute;

Comment: can you explain more your goal

Comment: The box only include text, no ">"  @KeesSonnema

Comment: Hm. allright I don't know what's wrong here. because I don't get what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to remove the blue focus box?

```
:focus {
    outline-color: transparent;
    outline-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I want to have the fouce style, but only include text, no ">"